# Playwright azure function doesn't install chromium Python based

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, playwright

I tried to execute an azure function based on Python and get this problem

[image: PlayWright Install]

PLAYWRITH_BROWSERS_PATH=0 is already set, also I tried put playwright install on requeriments.txt
but it doesn't work either. I've thinking in add a task in tasks.json on .vscode path but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PLAYWRITH_BROWSERS_PATH=0

Please make sure your above configuration was correct. There are some spelling mistakes in the settings. Its like `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH = 0`

In your **local.settings.json** it should be

```
{

"IsEncrypted": false,

    "Values": {
    
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
        
        "PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH": "0"
    
    }

}
```

And In your **requirement.txt** file it should be

```
azure-functions
playwright==1.18.0
```

here we can see the playwright running in local as well as azure after deployment
Local:
[image]

Azure:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: Hi, Delligansh

I've tried your solution, but it hasn't fixed the problem because in your HttpTrigger1 function you didn't use playwright, I guess your function doesn't run playwright instead for that reason your response was good.

I think that Azure functions can't run chromium, webkit ...; maybe one way to solve it is through virtual machines.

What's your opinion?

Comment: Using Virtual Machines is a good option. But you can check once with the Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by installing the drivers into the function project and defining the location in `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH`, as follows:

1. Create a `bin` folder in the project, here we want to store the drivers
2. Install the drivers in the bin folder using the following command, this installs the drivers in a `pw-browers` folder in the bin:

```
PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=./bin/pw-browsers python -m playwright install
```

3. Define the path to the drivers in `local.settings.json` AND in the Azure function project itself:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH": "./bin/pw-browsers"
  }
}
```

EDIT:
alternative solution:
https://github.com/anthonychu/20220303-python-func-playwright